# How to i make the sub string +1 after value 90

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to generate number's by adding 1 after the last number but the code does not want to add 1 after 90 and keep's generation a 10

The last number in my seq is 1918190 but the new seq i;m getting is 1918110

```
if (ecdCentre.getCenterID() == null || ecdCentre.getCenterID().isEmpty()) {
            sql = "SELECT concat(EC_CENTRE_REGION_ID, EC_CENTRE_CONSTITUENCY_ID, lpad( CASE WHEN MAX(SUBSTRING(EC_CENTRE_NO,6)) = '' THEN 0 ELSE MAX(SUBSTRING(EC_CENTRE_NO,6)) END  + 1 , 2, '0') ) centre_number FROM ecd_centre_reference WHERE EC_CENTRE_REGION_ID = ? AND EC_CENTRE_CONSTITUENCY_ID = ? ";
            centreNumber = template.queryForObject(sql,
                    new Object[] { ecdCentre.getRegionID(), ecdCentre.getConstituencyID() }, String.class);

            ecdCentre.setCenterID(centreNumber);

            System.out.println("Getting the con code: " + ecdCentre.getConstituencyID());
            System.out.println("Geting the re code: " + ecdCentre.getRegionID());
            System.out.println("Centre Number: " + centreNumber);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by converting the result from the table. first i had to convert the result into int as it as stored in a varchar format

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
            sql = "SELECT IFNULL(MAX(CONVERT( SUBSTRING(ec_centre_no, 6) , UNSIGNED INTEGER)), 0) + 1 new_centre_sequence FROM ecd_centre_reference "
                    + " WHERE ec_centre_region_id = ? AND ec_centre_constituency_id = ? ";
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````